# invalid data source name with PDO Sqlite

Tags: php, sql, pdo, ezsql

I'm having this error when trying to do a request from a PDO object (with ez_sql) on a sqlite database.

I read here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php that the db could be empty and that pdo will create automatically the db file.

So i do :

```
$ezSQL = new \ezSQL_pdo('sqlite:'.CHM.'/includes/stouv.sq3'); // file exists and is empty
// query on the $ezSQL object
```

And i get this error :

```
invalid data source name
```

I'm using the last version of WAMP with pdo_sqlite extension..

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What is the value of the `CHM` constant? The path to the file needs to be writable by PHP

Comment: only a dot: '.'. This: `$ezSQL = new \ezSQL_pdo('sqlite:includes/stouv.sq3');` product the same error.

Comment: Try `__DIR__ . '/includes/stouv.sq3'`. Is that file writable by PHP?

Comment: I found the problem (see below) thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, the problem was that `ez_sql` do not connect to the DB before the first query, because no username and password were set (second and third argument of the constructor).